# An array of array variable in Perl 6

Tags: raku

How can I **declare** and create a variable of type "array of array" in Perl 6? In the Perl's 6 documentation there's nothing about that. Theoretically, I can do this

```
@@var1
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: do you want to declare an array-of-arrays or a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: You don't have to specify what the outer array is comprised of. `my @array; @array[0][0] = 1`

Comment: @BradGilbert, Christoph said I have to.

Comment: The type declaration is optional, if you omit it you can put anything into an array, including other arrays.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: as mentioned, what I describe is a *type constraint* - (most) things will work without it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like any other type constraint, just put an `Array` in front of its name when declaring it:

```
my Array @array-of-arrays;
```

Now you can either assign an array as an element

```
@array-of-arrays[42] = [1, 2, 3];
```

or make use of auto-vivification

```
@array-of-arrays[1][2] = 42;
```

You could also choose the more liberal `Positional` as its element type, but this would break auto-vivification.

An array of arrays may be treated as multi-dimensional, so you can use a multi-index as well to access its elements:

```
@array-of-arrays[1;2] = 42;
```

As far as I'm aware, proper [multi-dimensional arrays](http://design.perl6.org/S09.html#Multidimensional_arrays) declared as

```
my @multi-dim-array[5;6];
```

have not been implemented in Rakudo yet, but they are supposed to arrive before Christmas.

Comment: what's the difference between `my Array @array-of-arrays;` and `my  @array-of-arrays;`?

Comment: check out `say (my @).WHAT` vs `say (my Array @).WHAT` - the former has type `Array`, the latter has type `Array[Array]`, ie an array that only accepts other arrays as elements

Comment: and how about array of array of array?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: in principle, `my Array[Array] @a`, but typed arrays are not very convenient to use in Perl6 as they are nominally typed instead of structurally; to add to `@a`, you'd have to do something like `@a[0] = (my Array @ = [])`; oftentimes, it's more pragmatic to leave your arrays untyped, but there are notable exceptions (eg natively typed arrays)

Comment: Just a note: you can even specify the type of Array: `my Array of Int @i;`